# operand should contain 1 column UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1241

what sql statements should i use to do something like this?

```
UPDATE 
`table1`
SET
`media` = 'url'
WHERE
`media` = '3' AND `forum_post_id` = ('109918','109949','109882','109819','109822')
```

right now i am getting the operand should contain 1 column error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "IN":

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `media` = 'url'
WHERE`media` = '3' AND `forum_post_id` IN ('109918','109949','109882','109819','109822')
```

[Documentation for "IN"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)